# adding class to current day with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

im making a calendar and i want to add a className to current day so i could highlight it but i got some troubles and i wanna please you for help

```
function getCurrentDayClass() {
        return day.format("DD-MM-YY") === dayjs().format("DD-MM-YY")
        //   document.getElementById().className += "current-day"
    }
```

```
<header>
                {rowIdx === 0 && (
                    <p>
                        {day.format('ddd').toUpperCase()}
                    </p>
                )}

                <p className="calendar-day">
                    {day.format("DD")}

                </p>

            </header>
```

Comment: `day.format("DD-MM-YY") === dayjs().format("DD-MM-YY")` is a conditional. You need to return the string value and invoke that function as the `className`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getCurrentDayClass() {
  if (day.format("DD-MM-YY") === dayjs().format("DD-MM-YY"))
    return "PUT_YOUR_CSS_CLASSNAME_HERE";// something like "cal-day active"
  return "calendar-day";
}
```

```html
<header>
  {rowIdx === 0 && (<p>{day.format('ddd').toUpperCase()}</p>)}
  <p className={getCurrentDayClass()}>{day.format("DD")}</p>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solve your problem

```
<p className=`${getCurrentDayClass() ? 'current-day-class' : ''}`
```

Comment: `getCurrentDayClass` needs to be invoked

Comment: @Andrew thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score -1):

When you push class with id in reactJS

```
   document.getElementById(id).classList.add("active")
```

When you push class with class in reactJS

```
    document.getElementsByClassName("example").classList.add("active")
```